# Node/Bluebird/MySQL transactions

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've been struggling with the Bluebird promise library and MySQL for the past week. I'm constantly finding that what doco there is assumes I'm totally immersed in their terminology and often only gives half the answer in it's examples, or none at all. Leaving me hanging trying to figure out how to use it.

Currently I'm trying to execute a series of SQL commands for creating a database record inside a transaction. I'm using this code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mysql = require('mysql');
Promise.promisifyAll(mysql);
Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/Connection').prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/Pool').prototype);

function getConnection() {
    return pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer(function (connection) {
        connection.release();
    });
}

function getTransaction(connection) {
    return connection.beginTransactionAsync().disposer(function (tx, promise) {
        if (promise.isFulfilled()) {
            tx.commitAsync();
        } else {
            tx.rollbackAsync();
        }
    });
}

Database.prototype.addStory = function (projectId, title, text) {
    return Promise.using(getConnection(), function (connection) {
        return Promise.using(getTransaction(connection), function () {
            return connection.queryAsync('INSERT INTO story SELECT ?, MAX(storyNumber) + 1, ?, ?, 0 FROM story WHERE projectID = ?',
                [projectId, title, text, projectId])
                .then(connection.queryAsync('select LAST_INSERT_ID()'))
                .then(function (rows) {
                    debug("Returning story for %s", rows[0]);
                    return getStory(connection, rows[0]);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And currently I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: tx.rollbackAsync is not a function
```

From what I've read my code should work. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: where is `pool` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers guys.

I've now found the [Knex](http://knexjs.org) API which solves all my problems with less code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the initial error and used this approach in my code:

```
function getTransaction(connection) {
    return connection.beginTransactionAsync().disposer(function (tx, promise) {
        if (promise.isFulfilled()) {
            connection.commitAsync();
        } else {
            connection.rollbackAsync();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Disposers are not a recommended way to manage transactions.  The documentation from Bluebird explains in detail why this is the case and gives some pretty good code examples for more robust options. See here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/api/disposer.md#note-about-disposers-in-node